# How to save image in mongoose using node api?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Below is my model

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;


var dummySchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    brand: {
        type: String
    },
    class: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    available: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true
    },

    dateavailable: {
        type: Date,
        default:Date.now    },
    avatar:{
        data:Buffer,
        contentType:String

    }
});



module.exports = mongoose.model('Dummy', dummySchema);
```

Express route to save new entity is below

```
app.post('/api/cars', function(req, res) {

        var dummy = new Dummy();
        dummy.name = req.body.name;
        dummy.brand = req.body.brand;
        dummy.class = req.body.class;
        dummy.price = req.body.price;
        dummy.available = true;
        dummy.avatar.data = fs.readFileSync(req.body.avatar);
        dummy.avatar.contentType="png";



        dummy.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.send("sucess");

        });
    });
```

When i'm trying to use postman to insert the data through http/post as below

[Screen shot from Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHMgH.jpg)

I'm getting the below error

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open &#39;E:\Fall_2015\SE\car_rental_software\server\https:\drive.google.com\file\d\0B9YLBjJ0zJ6YWDB4NUlFUThVS0E\view?usp=sharing&#39;
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Error (native)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:549:18)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:397:15)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at E:\Fall_2015\SE\car_rental_software\server\index.js:88:32
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Fall_2015\SE\car_rental_software\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (E:\Fall_2015\SE\car_rental_software\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Route.dispatch (E:\Fall_2015\SE\car_rental_software\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Fall_2015\SE\car_rental_software\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at E:\Fall_2015\SE\car_rental_software\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.process_params (E:\Fall_2015\SE\car_rental_software\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (E:\Fall_2015\SE\car_rental_software\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at methodOverride (E:\Fall_2015\SE\car_rental_software\server\node_modules\method-override\index.js:79:5)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Fall_2015\SE\car_rental_software\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at trim_prefix (E:\Fall_2015\SE\car_rental_software\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at E:\Fall_2015\SE\car_rental_software\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.process_params (E:\Fall_2015\SE\car_rental_software\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
```

Can anyone show me how to save image using Node API in  Mongoose?

Comment: it's trying to get it as a local file `E:\Fall_2015\SE\car_rental_software\server\https:\drive.google.com\file\d\0B9YLBjJ0zJ6YWDB4NUlFUThVS0E\view?usp=sharing&#39;` whereas it should be E:\Fall_2015\SE\car_rental_software\server\image.png or https:\drive.google.com\file\d\0B9YLBjJ0zJ6YWDB4NUlFUThVS0E\view?usp=sharing&#39;

Comment: of course  `fs.readFileSync ` vl try to read it as a file from local machine, but u r passing it  a hyperlink, so before doing fs.readFile make one more http call to `req.body.avatar` save it somewhere and then do readFile , ref this on how to make network call https://github.com/request/request
`request('http://google.com/doodle.png').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('doodle.png'))`

Comment: please find an example here : https://gist.github.com/aheckmann/2408370